# Overriding initialize on an AppDelegate - Protecting against code executing multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, uiapplicationdelegate

Overriding [`initialize()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1418639-initialize) is common for executing code before a class is sent its first message (setting UserDefaults, etc).  The documentation states that a superclass' implementation may be called multiple times subclasses do not override `initialize()`, and give an example of a way to protect a class from executing code more than once if `initialize()` is called several times:

> The superclass implementation may be called multiple times if subclasses do not implement `initialize()`—the runtime will call the inherited implementation—or if subclasses explicitly call `[super initialize]`. If you want to protect yourself from being run multiple times, you can structure your implementation along these lines:
>
> ```
> + (void)initialize {
>   if (self == [ClassName self]) {
>     // ... do the initialization ...
>   }
> }
> ```

I am overriding `initialize()` in my AppDelegate and trying to avoid having code run more than once.  The class check doesn't make sense to me, as checking if `self is AppDelegate.Type` will always evaluate to true (and gives me a warning in Xcode).

Does the class check not apply, since we're not in a superclass (the superclass of `AppDelegate` is `UIResponder`)?  Will the contents of my overridden `initialize()` method only run once without calling `super` or performing a class check?

Comment: I think if you use `===` instead of `is` it won't return true for subclasses of `AppDelegate`.

Comment: @dan Hmm, I didn't consider comparing references.  That is also a good option, and protects against subclasses.  You should post that as an answer.

Comment: Or `if self == AppDelegate.self`. But as long as you don't subclass AppDelegate, you don't need that check.

Comment: Does this question apply in Swift? I thought types handled initialization gracefully.

Comment: @MartinR we don't subclass AppDelegate right now, but ideally I want this to be as future proof as possible.

Comment: @BallpointBen Possibly pure Swift types, but I believe this still applies to any classes which inherit from `NSObject`.

Comment: I've never had any issues subclassing a subclass of `NSObject`. I've always done the easy, obvious thing, and it's worked.

Comment: @BallpointBen This isn't a question about subclassing, it's a question about overriding `initialize()` on a subclass.  There's nothing "obvious" here, unless you mean not checking the class or calling `super`.

Comment: I guess my point is, do you have a reason for doing that? Why not put all initialization code in `init`?

Comment: A (lazily called) static class property  is another option (the "dispatch_once replacement")

Comment: @BallpointBen is that safe?  I've never seen a case where `init` was overridden in an AppDelegate.

Comment: Actually AppDelegate is a special case, because there is always only one instance of it. So it makes no difference if you call the init code "once per instance" (override init) or "once per class" (override initialize).

Comment: Overriding `initialize` is marked as *deprecated* in Swift 3.1 (Xcode 8.3 beta 4) and will not work in future Swift versions: https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/6865.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, does overriding init still work?  What is your recommended approach?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the class check is because you usually want to run code on `initialize` only once (as per the docs). Writing that condition protects you from subclasses that don't implement `initialize` or call `[super initialize]`. Here's an example class hierarchy:

```
class Animal: NSObject {
    class func initialize() {
        //Some code I only want to run once
    }
}


class Dog: Animal {}
```

When I instantiate a new `Dog`, the Objective-C runtime will send the `initialize` method to *every class* in `Dog`'s hierarchy (superclasses first), so `Dog` will receive the message, but so will `Animal`. Because `Dog` doesn't implement `initialize`, its superclass will receive the message, so if you don't add the check that makes sure that the message was intended for that class, your code will end up executing twice.

This [doesn't really make sense in Swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/6865), and probably even less so in an AppDelegate so if you want to have code only run once in Swift, you should probably use lazily initialized globals or static properties, as defined in [the migration docs](https://swift.org/migration-guide/).